# Why do csh(tcsh) aliases not work when defined and invoked on one line?

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh

<sup>[Please do not recommend I not use csh. The Electrical Engineering community is inextricably bound to it. Thanks!]</sup>

When I do this:

```
csh -f -c "alias foo bar; foo"
```

I get:

> foo: Command not found.

Similarly, when I do this:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
alias foo bar; foo
```

I get the same `foo: Command not found.`. However, this works as expected:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
alias foo bar
foo
```

Which gives:

> bar: Command not found.

Is this just a bug in csh/tcsh? Or is this intentional? I have to deal with aliases since the environment I'm using depends heavily on them to configure toolsets (including modules). But this basically means I can't invoke short csh scripts with csh -f -c. I have to dump the commands to a file, chmod +x, and invoke it. Not a huge deal. But I'm just wondering if there's a way to trick this buggy/quirky shell into recognizing aliases defined on the same line.

Comment: You don't need to `chmod +x` files that are invoked directly with `csh`; you only need to do that when invoking as `./myscript.sh`.

Comment: See http://grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-0 and http://grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-2.

Comment: BTW, any particular reason you're using aliases rather than functions here?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Probably because csh and tcsh don't have functions.

Comment: Argh, just so. Hmm. If it's being called from bash, one can invoke `csh -f -c $'alias foo bar\nfoo'`, passing a newline as a literal.

Comment: Or, to allow invocation from any POSIX-y shell: `cmd=$(printf '%s\n' 'alias foo bar' 'foo'); csh -f -c "$cmd"`

Comment: @MylesPrather, ...you shouldn't need `/bin/sh` to run your script from Ruby -- you should be able to pass a direct argv array, so you can pass a literal script with newlines intact direct to `/bin/csh` in the first place.

Comment: Hmmm... All good food for thought. I'm bound to aliases because the CAD environment supplied to me uses them configure the environment for tool versions. I tried unrolling the aliases into their base components, but that was a headache and mysteriously wouldn't work right for a co-employee. As it turns out, I have gathered up enough lines in this script that I think it's cleaner to just write it out and call it (I like Jacob's shortcut; I get giddy every time I remove a line of code from the stuff I write). Thanks for all the good ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented behavior of csh: alias substitution happens after each input line is read and split into commands, but before any of the commands are executed (including your `alias` command).

From `csh(1)` manual:

> **Alias substitution**
>
> The shell maintains a list of aliases that can be established, displayed
>        and modified by the `alias` and `unalias` commands.  After a command line is     scanned, it is parsed into distinct commands and the first word of each
>        command, left-to-right, is checked to see if it has an alias.  If it
>        does, then the text that is the alias for that command is reread with the
>        history mechanism available as though that command were the previous
>        input line.  The resulting words replace the command and argument list.
>        If no reference is made to the history list, then the argument list is
>        left unchanged.

Comment: Excellent. Perfect explanation. That said, I tend to think it was a horrible design decision. Any sane user would think that ; is just a way to combine multiple lines into one. Ordinarily, it doesn't matter, except when you're trying to cram a short script into csh -f -c "....." for execution from an outer script (Ruby in my case [ie, /bin/sh]). Thanks Jacob!

Comment: It's a first mover disadvantage -- Bourne's Unix `sh` (and the original Thompson shell) didn't have aliases, so there was no precedent for how they should work when Joy started distributing `csh` with 2BSD in 1978.